# recorrer un xml y guardar en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dom

buenas tarde estoy tratando de recorrer este xml sin exito quisera saber que hago mal:

```
Este es mi codigo xml 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:sincronizarListaActividadesDocumentoSectorResponse xmlns:ns2="https://xxx/">
<RespuestaListaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<transaccion>true</transaccion>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>23</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FAC_PRE</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>29</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>NOT_CON</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>1</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FCV</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>24</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>NCD</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>13</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FSBAS</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>35</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FAC_CVB</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>40</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FSERZF</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>34</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>FAC_SEG</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>29</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>NCO</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>
<codigoDocumentoSector>47</codigoDocumentoSector>
<tipoDocumentoSector>NCDDE</tipoDocumentoSector>
</listaActividadesDocumentoSector>
</RespuestaListaActividadesDocumentoSector>
</ns2:sincronizarListaActividadesDocumentoSectorResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope> 
" no supe como insertar esta parte para preguntar"
```

este es el codigo que utilizo: despues de obtener el resultado en una variable $respeusta.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($respuesta);
if(isset($doc->getElementsByTagName('transaccion')->item(0)->nodeValue))
{
$transaccion = $doc->getElementsByTagName('transaccion')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

$nodo = $doc->getElementsByTagName('listaActividadesDocumentoSector');
$tamano = $nodo->length;
echo $tamano;
for ($i=0; $i <= $tamano; $i++) 
{               
$codigo = $nodo->getElementsByTagName('codigoActividad')->item($i)->nodeValue;            
$codigosector = $nodo->getElementsByTagName('codigoDocumentoSector')->item($i)->nodeValue;            
                $tiposector = $nodo->getElementsByTagName('tipoDocumentoSector')->item($i)->nodeValue;              

$sql = "SELECT * FROM act_doc_sector WHERE codigoactividad = $codigo";            
$consul = conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
$consul->execute();
if ($consul->rowCount()>=1)
{               
$sql ="UPDATE act_doc_sector SET cod_doc_sector = '$codigosector', tipo_doc_sector='$tiposector', transaccion='$transaccion', sucursal = '$sucur' WHERE codigoactividad = '$codigo'";
$consul = conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
$consul->execute();                         
}else{
$sql ="INSERT INTO act_doc_sector(codigoactividad, cod_doc_sector, tipo_doc_sector, transaccion, sucursal) VALUES('$codigo','$codigosector', '$tiposector','$transaccion','$sucur')";
$consul = conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
$consul->execute();             
}
}
```

estoy intentadno recorrer con DOM haciendo referencias al tagname, cuando el xml viene con un solo resultado puedo recorrer sin problemas, pero cuando vienen con varios resultados como este caso mi codigo solo guarda el ultimo registro.

cuando le hago un print_r o un var_dump puedo verificar que estan tdos los elementos en respuesta pero no puedo recorrerlos para guardarlos en mi base de datos.

Comment: La siguiente línea `$codigo = $nodo->getElementsByTagName('codigoActividad')->item($i)->nodeValue;` da un error, quizás deba cambiarla a `$codigo = $nodo->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('codigoActividad')->item(0)->nodeValue;`. Igualmente en el XML mostrado `<codigoActividad>360000</codigoActividad>` es siempre `360000`, es decir, todas las iteraciones serán sobre ese mismo `codigoActividad`.

Comment: Analiza la estructura de tu XML, el array de elementos está dentro del nodo: `RespuestaListaActividadesDocumentoSector`, por tanto, debes crear el array a recorrer haciendo referencia a dicho nodo. Actualmente tú intentas recorrer `listaActividadesDocumentoSector`, observa que CADA elemento se llama así. Dicho de otro modo, es `RespuestaListaActividadesDocumentoSector` quien contiene varios `listaActividadesDocumentoSector`. Si analizas el XML eso se ve clarísimo.